# Getting Live Audio and Live Video Stream from website that uses .swf

Tags: swift, flash, avfoundation, live-streaming

Hi so In my country there is a radio station called the edge, they have a mobile app and to be fair its ugly and shit. Mostly because they use something other than xcode so everything doesn't scale and it still uses ios 5 look. I am rebuilding there app from scratch because I cant take it anymore and it has to many bugs.

What I want is to get the live audio, and also their live video from there website which you can get from using inspect element. The problem is annoyingly they use flash so its .swf and I want to use apple built in frameworks to play it instead of using something stupid like a webview to load it, same goes with video I want to use apples frameworks and set a built in stream link,instead of loading a webview that they need to click before the build in safari web player opens.

The website is...
http://www.theedge.co.nz/Listen/MediaPopup/ListenLive.aspx
from inspect element you can get the audio link
http://static.mediaworks.co.nz/video/jw/6.90/jwplayer.flash.swf
and the video link is http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/federated_f9?&width=410&height=310&flashID=myExperience&bgcolor=%23000000&playerID=3890933753001&playerKey=AQ~~%2CAAADd5hvH7k~%2CnoUjxA7tBy3lfM0lqNQCvK27Yw9aCggD&isVid=true&isUI=true&dynamicStreaming=true&additionalAdTargetingParams=%3Bsect%3Dvideo-player%3Bsect1%3Dedgetv%3B&%40videoPlayer=3896209600001&includeAPI=true&localizedErrorXML=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.mediaworks.co.nz%2Fvideo%2Fbrightcove%2Fxml%2FlocalizedErrorXML.xml&autoStart=&debuggerID=&startTime=1449567152980

thanks for the help

Comment: SWF is just compiled code (and sometimes graphics for games sprites or user interfaces etc). Think of it as a variation on **.exe**, **.dmg**, **.apk**, **.ipa**... anyways my point is that the SWF at some point has been programmed to load an MP3 or AAC audio stream (or other codec supported by Flash such as NellyMosser etc), also their video player is likely playing h.264 video in some container format, from a random generated & expirable link (per current connection)... Anyways none of this is obvious by just using Inspect Elements or Network options.

Comment: Just make your app (to handle your own audio and video) then show them as demo and they might like it enough to allow you to legally stream their content or even buy it off you (PS: dont say "...to be fair its ugly and shit, try my new design").

Comment: The audio stream is simply using RTMP as can be clearly seen in the Network tab. The server & stream are in the page source, you can listen to it directly at `rtmp://live-non-geo.mediaworks.co.nz/live/theedge_96kbps`. They're using Wowza server so you can ditch Flash entirely and request a HLS source at `http://live-non-geo.mediaworks.co.nz/live/theedge_96kbps/playlist.m3u8`. The video doesn't load on Linux so I can't help you there.

Comment: Thank you! Big help! So i need to find a RTMP framework to play this stream on my app? Iv looked around because it doesnt look like the audio stream rtmp is supported by apple by default! Any Suggestions? Thanks again!